# Load markers from database as a toggleable layer

Tags: javascript, json, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to load markers from a database as a layer to my google map. I am already loading KML layers but I want the user to be able to save and load their own custom markers in my database.

My database structure looks like this:

```
| ID | TITLE | LAT | LON |
```

Since each user will have their own custom points, I want to get the user's points and load them as a layer on the map in addition to other default layers (KML). I read that creating a data layer would be the best approach, and also using geoJSON which I still don't know how to create from my database.

For now, I am using a generic json file just to see if I can actually add that as a toggleable layer but I can't get it right. Once I get that working, I can figure out how to get the results from the database and format it in geoJSON and add to the map.

This is how I have tried to get the json data as a toggleable layer but it doesn't work:

```
function initMap() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: {lat: -49.7770641, lng: 55.6602758},
    zoom: 6,
    mapTypeControlOptions: {
         position: google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_TOP
      },

  });

    layers[0] = new google.maps.KmlLayer('http://www.example.com/kmllayer1.kml', {preserveViewport: true, suppressInfoWindows: false, zIndex: 1});
    layers[1] = new google.maps.KmlLayer('http://www.example.com/kmllayer2.kml', {preserveViewport: true, zIndex: 2, suppressInfoWindows: true});
    layers[2] = map.data.loadGeoJson('https://storage.googleapis.com/maps-devrel/google.json');
    for (var i = 0; i < layers.length; i++) {
        layers[i].setMap(map);
      }
}
function toggleLayer(i) {
      if(layers[i].getMap() === null) {
        layers[i].setMap(map);
      }
      else {
        layers[i].setMap(null);
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data layer is different from [KmlLayer](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#KmlLayer), the [`.loadGeoJson`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#Data) method returns an array of [`Data.Feature`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#Data.Feature) objects.  From [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#Data):

> addGeoJson(geoJson:Object, options?:Data.GeoJsonOptions)
>
> Return Value:  `Array<Data.Feature>`
>
> Adds GeoJSON features to the collection. Give this method a parsed JSON. The imported features are returned. Throws an exception if the GeoJSON could not be imported.

Add it to your array of layers like this (note there is only one):

```
layers[2] = map.data;
layers[2].loadGeoJson(GEOJSON_URL);
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/f338ckh3/1/)

**code snippet:**

```js
var geocoder;
var map;
var layers = [];

function toggleLayer(i) {
  if (layers[i].getMap() === null) {
    layers[i].setMap(map);
  } else {
    layers[i].setMap(null);
  }
}

function initMap() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: {
      lat: 43,
      lng: -87
    },
    zoom: 4,
    mapTypeControlOptions: {
      position: google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_TOP
    },

  });

  layers[0] = new google.maps.KmlLayer('http://googlemaps.github.io/js-v2-samples/ggeoxml/cta.kml', {
    preserveViewport: true,
    suppressInfoWindows: false,
    zIndex: 2
  });
  layers[1] = new google.maps.KmlLayer('https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/us_states.kml', {
    preserveViewport: true,
    zIndex: 1,
    suppressInfoWindows: true
  });
  layers[2] = map.data;
  layers[2].loadGeoJson('http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/summary/2.5_week.geojson');
  for (var i = 0; i < layers.length; i++) {
    layers[i].setMap(map);
  }
  var btns = document.getElementsByClassName("btn");
  for (var i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(btns[i], 'click', (function(i) {
      return function() {
        toggleLayer(i);
      }
    })(i));
  }
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initMap);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<input class="btn" id="btn0" type="button" value="0" />
<input class="btn" id="btn1" type="button" value="1" />
<input class="btn" id="btn2" type="button" value="2" />
<div id="map"></div>
```

Comment: Works perfectly! I see where my error was. Thanks for taking the time to answer and also provide a snippet, much appreciated.